# Get requested column distinct values from list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list with multiple columns. I want to filter the list based on the requested column name (column name will come as a parameter) with distinct values.

```
IList<obj1> objTemp= new List<obj1>();
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
   obj1 temp= new obj1();
   temp.Name = "Name" + i;
   temp.Age= "Age" + i;
   temp.Company= "Company" + i;
   objTemp.Add(temp);
 }

var distinctTypeIDs = objTemp.Select(x => x.**{my requested column}**).Distinct();
```

Comment: You can use switch statement to check what is column name and than sort list based on that column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection for getting desired property by it's name:

```
var distinctTypeIDs = objTemp.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty("requested_column").GetValue(x))
                             .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, it is working for me but returning as list of objects type...can we get the same with same object (which i am using to do filter - objTemp)

Comment: @Mahendhar Select will always return the list of the object which has used inside expression, which is always one of the properties in your case. Could you please provide us with the input and output correclty?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a method like this.

```
private IList<obj1> SortListAccordingToParameter(string filter)
{
if(filter == "Name")
    return  objTemp.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct();
else if(filter == "Age")
    return objTemp.Select(x => x.Age).Distinct();
else if(filter == "Company")
    return objTemp.Select(x => x.Company).Distinct();
}
```

Comment: I assume that's meant to be x.Name, x.Age and x.Company in there.

Comment: Yes. The solution using reflection is better though.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "better" - sure my expression solution or the reflection / anonymous types implementations are fine, but yours probably executes the fastest and is the most clear. If I knew the type definition would never change, I'd probably go with something like what you have.

Comment: it may work but I have many columns, it is difficult to add new column when ever i change/add/delete the column/property of the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the type of the property you will be searching for, you could use expressions.

```
string propName = "Age";
var paramExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Obj1));
// o =>

var memberExpression = Expression.Property(paramExpression, propName);
// o => o.Age

var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Obj1, string>>(memberExpression, paramExpression);
// (o => o.Age)

var compiled = lambdaExpression.Compile();

IList<Obj1> objTemp = new List<Obj1>();
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    Obj1 temp = new Obj1();
    temp.Name = "Name" + i;
    temp.Age = "Age" + i;
    temp.Company = "Company" + i;
    objTemp.Add(temp);
}

var results = objTemp.Select(compiled);
// equivalent to objTemp.Select(o => o.Age), plus a delegate call and the time to 
// compile the lambda.
```

I would probably wrap this up in a static class, like this:

```
static class Gen<TModel, TProp> {
    public static Func<TModel, TProp> SelectorExpr(string propertyName) {
        var pExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TModel));
        var mExpr = Expression.Property(pExpr, propertyName);
        var lExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProp>>(mExpr, pExpr);
        return lExpr.Compile();
    }
}
```

that way you can write your selector like:

```
var results = objTemp.Select(Gen<Obj1, string>.SelectorExpr(propName));
```

That seems a bit more clear to me what it is I'm doing, especially if I'm reading expression DOM code I wrote 6 months after.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a fan of "mapping" a column to an anonymous method responsible for retrieving the contents of that column:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        var items = new List<SomeObject> {new SomeObject { Age = 10, Name = "Daniel", Company = "InCycle" },
                                         {new SomeObject { Age = 20, Name = "Not Daniel", Company = "Not InCycle" }
                                         }};

        var result = Filter<int>(items, "Age");
        Console.WriteLine(result.Last());

    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<SomeObject> items, string filterCriteria)
    {
        var mappings = new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<SomeObject>, IEnumerable<T>>>
        {
            { "Age", filterItems => filterItems.Select(item => item.Age).Distinct().Cast<T>() }, 
            { "Name", filterItems => filterItems.Select(item => item.Name).Distinct().Cast<T>() }, 
            { "Company", filterItems => filterItems.Select(item => item.Company).Distinct().Cast<T>() }
        };

        return mappings[filterCriteria](items);

    }
}

public class SomeObject
{
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Company {get; set;}
}
```

The downside to this approach is that if you add additional properties, you could forget to add them to the filtering. Expressions are a solid approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Test
 {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string contact { get; set; }

    public Test getName(string name)
    {
        List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();

        testList.Add(new Test { name = "Developer", age = "24", contact = "99009900990" });
        testList.Add(new Test { name = "Tester", age = "30", contact = "009900990099" });

        return testList.Where(c => c.name == name).FirstOrDefault();
    }
  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        Test testObj = new Test();
        Test selectedObj = testObj.getName("Developer");
  }
```